# Jquery AJAX with WebService State 500

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm stuck with this stupid issue, trying to make Jason call to load data from database.
it gives me the stupid error of" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) "http://localhost:4695/SAW.WEB.ONLINE/AutoComplete.asmx/GetMapInfoDiv?{'conType':'2','conID':'5'}"

The weservice, and the function are working just fine. I tested them, the url for the web service is correct, I used for ajax autocomplete and it works fine, I even used the ajax autocomplete on the same page.

here is my web service method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetMapInfoDiv(string conType, string conID)
{
    DBLink objResult = new DBLink();
    objResult = GenericContent.GetMapInfoDiv((MapMarkerType)
     Convert.ToInt32(conType),      Convert.ToInt32(conID));
    return Convert.ToString(objResult.dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
}
```

and here is my javascript call.

```
 function LoadInfoDivByType(ContentType, ContentID) {

    var html;
    $.ajax(
 {
     Type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

     url: "../AutoComplete.asmx/GetMapInfoDiv",
     data: JSON.stringify({ conType: ContentType, conID: ContentID }), //{conType:"'" +ContentType+ "'",conID:"'" + ContentID + "'"}, //
     //data: "{'conType':'" + '2' + "','conID':'3'}",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (msg) {
         html = msg.d;
         alert(html);
     }
 });

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget to write like this `ScriptMethod`

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Result(string controlName, int sleep)
{
```

also in jquery part remove `JSON.stringify` function

```
data: { "conType": ContentType, "conID" : ContentID }
```

Check : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-Call-to-ASP.Net-Server-Side-Web-service-method-using-jQuery.aspx